# Yii orm - is-a relationship (generalization)

Tags: php, orm, yii

Is it possible with the yii ORM to make a is-a relationship?

My relation schema is:

```
User (username (pk), email)
Employee (username (fk))
Boss (username (fk), field1)
```

Are there any best practices in general for this scenario using php with any ORM?

Can I simply derive from User and Employee, but I think this cannot work because the system has to know in which table the actual values live.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the documentation on relations.

Answer (score 0):

Its all your choice how you want to implement things.You can also have a `single table` and use `scenarios` to separate required inputs and separate validations. `Yii` is very flexible and strong ORM so what you need is to start reading the documentations and make your way further.